# Register a webhook for lead notification

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to register a webhook such that once a lead is received a notificaton is snet to the webhook. The endpoint  is lead notification.

[image: postman]

Wasn trying to register a webhook using postman, but it isnt working.